# how to add text preprocessing tokenization step into Tensorflow model

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, data-preprocessing

I have a TensorFlow model `SavedModel` which includes `saved_model.pb` and `variables` folder. The preprocessing step has not been incorporated into this model that's why I need to do preprocessing(Tokenization etc) before feeding the data to the model for the prediction aspect.

I am looking for an approach that I can incorporate the preprocessing step into the model. I have seen examples [here](https://cloud.google.com/blog/topics/developers-practitioners/add-preprocessing-functions-tensorflow-models-and-deploy-vertex-ai) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59344187/tensorflow-2-0-add-image-preprocessing-step-in-a-saved-model) however they are image data.

Just to get an idea how the training part has been done, this is a portion of the code that we did training (if you need the implementation of the function I have used here, please let me know(I did not include it to make my question more understandable ))

***Training:***

```
processor = IntentProcessor(FLAGS.data_path, FLAGS.test_data_path,
                            FLAGS.test_proportion, FLAGS.seed, FLAGS.do_early_stopping)


bert_config = modeling.BertConfig.from_json_file(FLAGS.bert_config_file)
tokenizer = tokenization.FullTokenizer(
    vocab_file=FLAGS.vocab_file, do_lower_case=FLAGS.do_lower_case)

run_config = tf.estimator.RunConfig(
    model_dir=FLAGS.output_dir,
    save_checkpoints_steps=FLAGS.save_checkpoints_steps)

train_examples = None
num_train_steps = None
num_warmup_steps = None
if FLAGS.do_train:
    train_examples = processor.get_train_examples()
    num_iter_per_epoch = int(len(train_examples) / FLAGS.train_batch_size)
    num_train_steps = num_iter_per_epoch * FLAGS.num_train_epochs
    num_warmup_steps = int(num_train_steps * FLAGS.warmup_proportion)
    run_config = tf.estimator.RunConfig(
        model_dir=FLAGS.output_dir,
        save_checkpoints_steps=num_iter_per_epoch)

best_temperature = 1.0  # Initiate the best T value as 1.0 and will
# update this during the training

model_fn = model_fn_builder(
    bert_config=bert_config,
    num_labels=len(processor.le.classes_),
    init_checkpoint=FLAGS.init_checkpoint,
    learning_rate=FLAGS.learning_rate,
    num_train_steps=num_train_steps,
    num_warmup_steps=num_warmup_steps,
    best_temperature=best_temperature,
    seed=FLAGS.seed)

estimator = tf.estimator.Estimator(
    model_fn=model_fn,
    config=run_config)
# add parameters by passing a prams variable

if FLAGS.do_train:
    train_features = convert_examples_to_features(
        train_examples, FLAGS.max_seq_length, tokenizer)
    train_labels = processor.get_train_labels()
    train_input_fn = input_fn_builder(
        features=train_features,
        is_training=True,
        batch_size=FLAGS.train_batch_size,
        seed=FLAGS.seed,
        labels=train_labels
    )
    estimator.train(input_fn=train_input_fn, max_steps=num_train_steps)
```

And this is the preprocessing that I use for the training:

```
LABEL_LIST = ['negative', 'neutral', 'positive']
INTENT_MAP = {i: LABEL_LIST[i] for i in range(len(LABEL_LIST))}
BATCH_SIZE = 1
MAX_SEQ_LEN = 70
def convert_examples_to_features(texts, max_seq_length, tokenizer):
    """Loads a data file into a list of InputBatchs.
       texts is the list of input text
    """
    features = {}
    input_ids_list = []
    input_mask_list = []
    segment_ids_list = []

    for (ex_index, text) in enumerate(texts):
        tokens_a = tokenizer.tokenize(str(text))
        # Account for [CLS] and [SEP] with "- 2"
        if len(tokens_a) > max_seq_length - 2:
            tokens_a = tokens_a[0:(max_seq_length - 2)]
        tokens = []
        segment_ids = []
        tokens.append("[CLS]")
        segment_ids.append(0)
        for token in tokens_a:
            tokens.append(token)
            segment_ids.append(0)
        tokens.append("[SEP]")
        segment_ids.append(0)

        input_ids = tokenizer.convert_tokens_to_ids(tokens)
        # print(tokens)

        # The mask has 1 for real tokens and 0 for padding tokens. Only real
        # tokens are attended to.
        input_mask = [1] * len(input_ids)

        # Zero-pad up to the sequence length.
        while len(input_ids) < max_seq_length:
            input_ids.append(0)
            input_mask.append(0)
            segment_ids.append(0)

        assert len(input_ids) == max_seq_length
        assert len(input_mask) == max_seq_length
        assert len(segment_ids) == max_seq_length

        input_ids_list.append(input_ids)
        input_mask_list.append(input_mask)
        segment_ids_list.append(segment_ids)

    features['input_ids'] = np.asanyarray(input_ids_list)
    features['input_mask'] = np.asanyarray(input_mask_list)
    features['segment_ids'] = np.asanyarray(segment_ids_list)

    # tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices needs to pass numpy array not
    # tensor, or the tensor graph (shape) should match

    return features
```

and inferencing would be like this:

```
def inference(texts,MODEL_DIR, VOCAB_FILE):
    if not isinstance(texts, list):
        texts = [texts]
    tokenizer = FullTokenizer(vocab_file=VOCAB_FILE, do_lower_case=False)
    features = convert_examples_to_features(texts, MAX_SEQ_LEN, tokenizer)

    predict_fn = predictor.from_saved_model(MODEL_DIR)
    response = predict_fn(features)
    #print(response)
    return get_sentiment(response)

def preprocess(texts):
    if not isinstance(texts, list):
        texts = [texts]
    tokenizer = FullTokenizer(vocab_file=VOCAB_FILE, do_lower_case=False)
    features = convert_examples_to_features(texts, MAX_SEQ_LEN, tokenizer)

    return features

def get_sentiment(response):
    idx = response['intent'].tolist()
    print(idx)
    print(INTENT_MAP.get(idx[0]))
    outputs = []
    for i in range(0, len(idx)):
        outputs.append({
            "sentiment": INTENT_MAP.get(idx[i]),
            "confidence": response['prob'][i][idx[i]]
        })
    return outputs

    sentence = 'The movie is ok'
    inference(sentence, args.model_path, args.vocab_path)
```

And this is the implementation of `model_fn_builder`:

```
def model_fn_builder(bert_config, num_labels, init_checkpoint, learning_rate,
                     num_train_steps, num_warmup_steps, best_temperature, seed):
    """Returns multi-intents `model_fn` closure for Estimator"""

    def model_fn(features, labels, mode,
                 params):  # pylint: disable=unused-argument
        """The `model_fn` for Estimator."""

        tf.logging.info("*** Features ***")
        for name in sorted(features.keys()):
            tf.logging.info(
                "  name = %s, shape = %s" % (name, features[name].shape))

        input_ids = features["input_ids"]
        input_mask = features["input_mask"]
        segment_ids = features["segment_ids"]

        is_training = (mode == tf.estimator.ModeKeys.TRAIN)

        (total_loss, per_example_loss, logits) = create_intent_model(
            bert_config, is_training, input_ids, input_mask, segment_ids,
            labels, num_labels, mode, seed)

        tvars = tf.trainable_variables()

        initialized_variable_names = None
        if init_checkpoint:
            (assignment_map,
             initialized_variable_names) = \
                modeling.get_assignment_map_from_checkpoint(
                    tvars, init_checkpoint)

            tf.train.init_from_checkpoint(init_checkpoint, assignment_map)

        tf.logging.info("**** Trainable Variables ****")
        for var in tvars:
            init_string = ""
            if var.name in initialized_variable_names:
                init_string = ", *INIT_FROM_CKPT*"
            tf.logging.info("  name = %s, shape = %s%s", var.name, var.shape,
                            init_string)

        output_spec = None
        if mode == tf.estimator.ModeKeys.TRAIN:

            train_op = optimization.create_optimizer(
                total_loss, learning_rate, num_train_steps, num_warmup_steps)

            output_spec = tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec(
                mode=mode,
                loss=total_loss,
                train_op=train_op)

        elif mode == tf.estimator.ModeKeys.EVAL:

            def metric_fn(per_example_loss, labels, logits):
                predictions = tf.argmax(logits, axis=-1, output_type=tf.int32)
                accuracy = tf.metrics.accuracy(labels, predictions)
                loss = tf.metrics.mean(per_example_loss)
                return {
                    "eval_accuracy": accuracy,
                    "eval_loss": loss
                }

            eval_metrics = metric_fn(per_example_loss, labels, logits)
            output_spec = tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec(
                mode=mode,
                loss=total_loss,
                eval_metric_ops=eval_metrics)

        elif mode == tf.estimator.ModeKeys.PREDICT:
            predictions = {
                'intent': tf.argmax(logits, axis=-1, output_type=tf.int32),
                'prob': tf.nn.softmax(logits / tf.constant(best_temperature)),
                'logits': logits
            }
            output_spec = tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec(
                mode=mode,
                predictions=predictions)

        return output_spec

    return model_fn
```

And this is the implementation of `create_intent_model`

```
def create_intent_model(bert_config, is_training, input_ids, input_mask,
                        segment_ids,
                        labels, num_labels, mode, seed):
    model = modeling.BertModel(
        config=bert_config,
        is_training=is_training,
        input_ids=input_ids,
        input_mask=input_mask,
        token_type_ids=segment_ids,
        use_one_hot_embeddings=False,
        seed=seed
    )
    output_layer = model.get_pooled_output()

    hidden_size = output_layer.shape[-1].value

    with tf.variable_scope("loss"):
        output_weights = tf.get_variable(
            "output_weights", [num_labels, hidden_size],
            initializer=tf.truncated_normal_initializer(stddev=0.02, seed=seed))
        output_bias = tf.get_variable(
            "output_bias", [num_labels], initializer=tf.zeros_initializer())

        if is_training:
            # I.e., 0.1 dropout
            output_layer = tf.nn.dropout(output_layer, keep_prob=0.9, seed=seed)

        logits = tf.matmul(output_layer, output_weights, transpose_b=True)
        logits = tf.nn.bias_add(logits, output_bias)

        loss = None
        per_example_loss = None

        if mode == tf.estimator.ModeKeys.TRAIN or mode == \
                tf.estimator.ModeKeys.EVAL:
            log_probs = tf.nn.log_softmax(logits, axis=-1)

            one_hot_labels = tf.one_hot(labels, depth=num_labels,
                                        dtype=tf.float32)

            per_example_loss = -tf.reduce_sum(one_hot_labels * log_probs,
                                              axis=-1)

            loss = tf.reduce_mean(per_example_loss)

        return loss, per_example_loss, logits
```

This is the list `tensorflow` related libraries:

```
tensorboard==1.15.0
tensorflow-estimator==1.15.1
tensorflow-gpu==1.15.0
```

There is good documentation [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/preprocessing_layers), however, it uses Keras API. Plus, I don't know how can I incorporate preprocessing layer here even with the Keras API.

Again, my final goal is to incorporate the preprocessing step into the model building phase so that when I later load the model I directly pass the `The movie is ok` to the model?

I just need the idea on how to incorporate a preprocessing layer into this code which is function based.

Thanks in advance~

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `TextVectorization` layer as follows. But to answer your question fully, I'd need to know what's in `model_fn_builder()` function. I'll show how you can do this with Keras model building API.

```
class BertTextProcessor(tf.keras.layers.Layer):

  def __init__(self, max_length):
    super().__init__()
    self.max_length = max_length
    # Here I'm setting any preprocessing to none
    # by default this layer lowers case and remove punctuation
    # i.e. tokens like [CLS] would become cls
    self.vectorizer = tf.keras.layers.TextVectorization(output_sequence_length=max_length, standardize=None)

  def call(self, inputs):

    inputs = "[CLS] " + inputs + " [SEP]"
    tok_inputs = self.vectorizer(inputs)

    return {
        "input_ids": tok_inputs, 
        "input_mask": tf.cast(tok_inputs != 0, 'int32'),
        "segment_ids": tf.zeros_like(tok_inputs)
        }

  def adapt(self, data):
    data = "[CLS] " + data + " [SEP]"
    self.vectorizer.adapt(data)

  def get_config(self):
    return {
        "max_length": self.max_length
    }
```

Usage,

```
input_str = tf.constant(["movie is okay good plot very nice", "terrible movie bad actors not good"])

proc = BertTextProcessor(8)
# You need to call this so that the vectorizer layer learns the vocabulary
proc.adapt(input_str)
print(proc(input_str))
```

which outputs,

```
{'input_ids': <tf.Tensor: shape=(2, 10), dtype=int64, numpy=
array([[ 5,  2, 12,  9,  3,  8,  6, 11,  4,  0],
       [ 5,  7,  2, 13, 14, 10,  3,  4,  0,  0]])>, 'input_mask': <tf.Tensor: shape=(2, 10), dtype=int32, numpy=
array([[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0]], dtype=int32)>, 'segment_ids': <tf.Tensor: shape=(2, 10), dtype=int64, numpy=
array([[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]])>}
```

You can use this layer as an input for a Keras model as you would use any layer.

You can also get the vocabulary using, `proc.vectorizer.get_vocabulary()` which returns,

```
['',
 '[UNK]',
 'movie',
 'good',
 '[SEP]',
 '[CLS]',
 'very',
 'terrible',
 'plot',
 'okay',
 'not',
 'nice',
 'is',
 'bad',
 'actors']
```

### Alternative with `tf-models-official`

To get data in a format accepted by BERT, you can also use the `tf-models-official` library. Specifically, you can use the [`BertPackInputs` object](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tfm/nlp/layers/BertPackInputs).

I recently updated code for one of my books and in [Chapter 13/13.1_Spam_Classification](https://github.com/thushv89/manning_tf2_in_action/blob/master/Ch13-Transormers-with-TF2-and-Huggingface/13.1_Spam_Classification_with_BERT.ipynb) you can see how it is used. The section *Generating the correct input format for BERT* shows how this could be done.

### Edit: How to do this in `tensorflow==1.15.0`

In order to do this in TensorFlow 1.x you will need some reworking as lot of functionality in the original answer is missing. Here's an example of how you can do this, you will need to adapt this code accordingly to your specific usecase/method.

```
lookup_layer = tf.lookup.StaticHashTable(
    tf.lookup.TextFileInitializer(
      "vocab.txt", tf.string, tf.lookup.TextFileIndex.WHOLE_LINE,
      tf.int64, tf.lookup.TextFileIndex.LINE_NUMBER, delimiter=" "),
      100
) 

text = tf.constant(["bad film", "movie is okay good plot very nice", "terrible movie bad actors not good"])
text = "[CLS]" + text + "[SEP]"
text = tf.strings.split(text, result_type="RaggedTensor")
text_dense = text.to_tensor("[PAD]")

out = lookup_layer.lookup(text_dense)

with tf.Session() as sess:
  sess.run(tf.tables_initializer())
  print(sess.run(out))
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your response. I will read it carefully and I will get back to you if that's ok. but to answer your question, I have updated  my question with `model_fn_builder`. Thanks again for taking the time. I could not find any straightforward documentation for tensorflow!

Comment: Yeah skimming through it I think this should work with minimal integration effort (never tried it myself though)

Comment: Im out of town and will check your solution on Thursday. thanks so much again

Comment: again thanks so much for providing the solution. I just notice that the bounty has not been assigned to your answer ;/. I will run a new one and will assign it to your solution. Back to the question, Im trying to incorporate your solution into the model but honestly not sure how to incorporate that class into the model building. Was wondering if you can please share how can I do that?

Comment: Also, is there any chapter summary of your book? I wanted to see which kind of subjects has been covered? https://www.amazon.com/Natural-Language-Processing-TensorFlow-sought-after-ebook/dp/B09X7STVKX/ref=tmm_kin_swatch_0?_encoding=UTF8&qid=&sr=

Comment: @sariii, hey thanks for the interest :) If you click "Look inside" just above the book cover on the left, you should see the book's roadmap, ToC, etc.

Comment: thank you I will certainly look into it. I was wondering if you could add some explanations on how to call `BertTextProcessor` in the model function

Comment: Hi @thushv89 I have not implemented it in my code yet. Sorry for the naive question but why `BertTextProcessor` has two input parameters? I understand that one of them is for `max_length` but what the other input parameter stands for?

Comment: Hey @sariii, shoot, that's just a remnant from some experimentation I did. It shouldnt be there. Also, one more thing (I recently found out) is using `tf-models-official` library for this purpose. I'll add a section at the bottom with some links to code examples.

Comment: Thanks so much @thushv89. That would be great and I think your current solution needs the recent version of tensorflow, am I right? For some reason I have to stick with tensorflow version 1. Is there any solution around that? (I am still eager to see your alternative solution with `tf-models-official`)

Comment: For the first solution, it should work with any version that has the `TextVectorization` layer. Did you run into issues? For the one using `tf-models-official`. Yes it it quite new and you'd probably need to use tf `>=2.8`.

Comment: Yea, I ran into this error `AttributeError: module 'tensorflow.python.keras.api._v1.keras.layers' has no attribute 'TextVectorization'`

Comment: Can you tell me which version of `tf` you need to use (and versions of any other dependencies you can think of)? I'll have a look when I get some time :)

Comment: I really appreciate it @thushv89, I just updated the question with the list of libraries. Could you please copy it and then I will remove it to make the question is more readable?

Comment: All good. I've edited the post. It'll be better we keep that info there in case someone else already knows a solution, they can jump in before me :)

Comment: so sorry to bug you :/ but is there any hope for this?

Comment: Hey @sariii, all good. Sorry didn't get a chance to look at this. It seems like you'll need a custom vectorizer. Also, one thing I wanted to check, this is a pretrained model with a tokenizer right? This means, we cannot use an arbitrary mapping of words to IDs. Just wanted to double check

Comment: Thanks so much for getting back to me. Yes that's correct (We trained BERT from scratch on our data and then we use that Bert to classify texts to three categories, positive, negative, neutral).

Comment: Is there any easy way to build that custom vectorizer provided that I have access to the `vocabulary` (30k vocab)

Comment: Oh right, so you have the vocabulary (including special tokens)? I think we should be able to. :) Can you upload it and add that to the question?

Comment: Greaaat, do we need the exact file? can we do it with a sample? its a `.txt` file like the uncased version of Bert that is available in the internet with this difference that it has been tried on our data that's why the vocals are different.

Comment: Okay then can you link the original file you used. Don't need the custom one.

Comment: Please let me know in case you don't have access to it https://drive.google.com/file/d/1CNnfR5wxLFWjrklPF5eky5TCzmqTqZ10/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247187/discussion-between-thushv89-and-sariii).